# Django - Privatizing Code - Which files are served to a user?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to develop an API using an algorithm I wrote.

When someone requests a url, my urls.py calls a function in views.py which serves

page that returns a JSON string.

If my algorithm is in my views.py file, or in another file on my server, would it be possible for a user to view the contents of this file, and then see my algorithm?

In other words, when using Django, which files will never be served to a user, and which files will be?

Is there any way I can stop someone from viewing my algorithm if it's in a .py file? Other than Chmodding the file or encrypting the code?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django only serves the responses that you explicitly create and return from your views.  There is no general ability to request files from it.

Make sure your source code isn't in a directory that your web server is configured to serve from, and make sure your `settings.py` value for `DEBUG` is `False`, and you should be fine.  Oh, and just in case - don't try to use the Django development server in production.

Comment: I'm assuming there are many guides on getting a project production-ready?

Comment: The official docs and their linked resources are pretty good: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Comment: Could you please expand more on this "Make sure your source code isn't in a directory that your web server is configured to serve from".
Thanks.

Comment: Suppose you're using Apache with, say, `/usr/local/apache/htdocs` set as your docroot.  If your Django source code is under that directory and your allow/deny rules allow it, a user could request your source code from Apache.  You don't want to let that happen.  Instead, your source code should be stored outside the directories that Apache is set to allow access to.  You'd then use `mod_wsgi` and its `WSGIScriptAlias` directive to tell Apache that requests matching a particular URL go to your Django app's handler.  It's nothing like a server-side PHP page with the code mixed into the markup.

Answer (score 1):

As long as nobody has shell access to your server, people will never see more than the actual HTML output of your page. .py files are not shown to the user that has requested an url in the browser.

Comment: If a user visited my views.py file in their browser, they wouldn't see source code? Are .py and PHP files similar in this sense?

Comment: He cannot directly visit your source files in usual cases because the web server is configured to only serve the final output. I would recommend to read about some basics.